# How to compress data send to firestore?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

currently I use firestore to store all key/value of user. I use

```
allkeys=prefs.getKeys().map<String>((key) {
        return key + ":" + prefs.get(key).toString();
      }).toList();
```

to sav in one file all data.

If user want to load his data, I extract each data from this unique string to assign in the good place.

OK is very bad. But I search a solution to compress data

If there is a solution to reduce long code

```
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
```

to

```
S/oI9tASZL0FO4fbtOM8Yw/fOM3DgHjo8bqVe
```

It will be very help full, It can peharps solve this error

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Cloud Firestore (24.2.1).
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue.lambda$panic$3(AsyncQueue.java:19)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.-$$Lambda$AsyncQueue$jx84dqgUsF4ojecSMurRqFLFD1Y.run(-.java:2)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7529)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)


Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor.lambda$executeAndReportResult$1(AsyncQueue.java:14)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.-$$Lambda$AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$pKSAgg-ozJ8RbUveSl-44aUfFQw.run(-.java:4)
       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$DelayedStartFactory.run(AsyncQueue.java:15)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)



Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
       at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetBlob(CursorWindow.java)
       at android.database.CursorWindow.getBlob(CursorWindow.java:405)
       at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getBlob(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:45)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache.processOverlaysInBackground(SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache.java:1)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache.lambda$processSingleCollection$1(SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache.java)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache.lambda$processSingleCollection$1$SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache(SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache.java)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.-$$Lambda$SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache$cYi4Cr9jm_0SezP9UVaUuAt693w.accept(-.java:8)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLitePersistence$Query.forEach(SQLitePersistence.java:13)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache.processSingleCollection(SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache.java:54)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache.getOverlays(SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache.java:78)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.LocalDocumentsView.populateOverlays(LocalDocumentsView.java:33)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.LocalDocumentsView.getOverlayedDocuments(LocalDocumentsView.java:9)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.LocalStore.lambda$writeLocally$2(LocalStore.java:55)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.LocalStore.lambda$writeLocally$2$LocalStore(LocalStore.java)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.-$$Lambda$LocalStore$cg_93_KSzr574nUI4weqpmjMR0A.get(-.java:8)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLitePersistence.runTransaction(SQLitePersistence.java:20)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.LocalStore.writeLocally(LocalStore.java:42)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.SyncEngine.writeMutations(SyncEngine.java:7)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient.lambda$write$12(FirestoreClient.java:2)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient.lambda$write$12$FirestoreClient(FirestoreClient.java)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.-$$Lambda$FirestoreClient$EkV-69Na9I9DmQjVN9C_ABIfHUQ.run(-.java:6)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue.lambda$enqueue$2(AsyncQueue.java)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.-$$Lambda$AsyncQueue$Y9GO7zO2DX6MzQJ5TbKtKW_NzO0.call(-.java:2)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor.lambda$executeAndReportResult$1(AsyncQueue.java)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.-$$Lambda$AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$pKSAgg-ozJ8RbUveSl-44aUfFQw.run(-.java:4)
       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$DelayedStartFactory.run(AsyncQueue.java:15)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
```

Comment: please share an imgae of your database

Comment: Also you might want to save the data as a map. `{'user_prefs":"my long long string"}`, this way you can manipulate the long string.

Comment: I have only a collection "Save", with inside user id, inside my data that I replace after each modification of user in the app  in this format [2022-07-20,increment_color_h17_consommation:1.0, sante11_succes:false, save_max_list:[2022-08-13 18:11, 2022-08-13 19:20], etc...

Comment: then structure your data as follows `Save/userid` , `document {'my_key':'my data'}`, you dont need to worry about the string being long

Comment: currently when user have lot of data to write on, he have a crash as mention, apparently the limitation is 2mo

Comment: Have a look at this stackoverflow [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64030619/18265638) & [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50739346/java-lang-runtimeexception-internal-error-in-firestore-0-6-6-dev)