# Does Firebase Firestore compress json data when sending it over the network?

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I use Firebase Firestore as a backend for my iOS app. The data is stored in a document style in Firestore as usual. And I receive (read) it as JSON in my app.
Question: Does Firestore compress the data when users read it from the DB? Like gzip it? Or does it send the raw text json?

I've searched the docs for "compression" and couldn't find anything. I've, however, found this old SO  [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64028654/does-firestore-compress-docs-data-before-sending-it-to-the-client) saying: "No data compression is performed on the document data by the Firestore clients or servers." Which seems odd to me, as I thought it could benefit from gzip. Is that info still valid?

Comment: Data is not compressed, As then it would have to be zipped and unzipped etc and that wastes a lot of CPU cycles - and would impact the responsiveness of Firebase products in general. *You* can compress your data if you want to though. Why do you ask?

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Jay! I'm asking because there is a size difference between raw and gzipped json. I'm sad to hear that Firebase doesn't compress data. Gzipped data could be twice-thrice less Kb and that would make a difference in loading content for my app.

Comment: I see. I am not sure saving kb would be worth the overall speed impact - the data would have to be compressed on the client side and then uncompressed on the server to be stored as JSON and vice-versa. You can certainly compress data before storing though - although that would make queries etc more challenging. I like the question though as it really is not spelled out anywhere in the docs.